# angularjs1.4 CORS failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.3. Here's my code:

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .run(run);

function run($http) {

      a = $http({
          method: "GET",
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/test',
          data: {}
      });

      console.log(a);
}
```

Using browser or Postman can get it correct. But the code above gives

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/test. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

The point is, I can use GET method to get the result using applications. But using code won't work. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You can either set proxy using grunt-proxy or allow CORS on server side. How to do this, depends on server technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The point is, I can use GET method to get the result using applications.

In that instance, there is the application and the server and nobody else. There are only two entities involved.

> But using code won't work.

You have two different websites (localhost:8000 and localhost:8080) and the browser doesn't know if the JavaScript provided by 8000 can be trusted with the data that 8080 is willing to give to the user.

> What have I done wrong?

You haven't provided an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the HTTP response from 8080 to tell the browser that 8000 can be trusted with the data.

See also:

- [The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)
- [The MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: +1. As a small aside, *"In that instance, there is the application and the server and nobody else. There are only two entities involved."* - I think the asker means that he/she can access the website through an application like a browser, not referring to the web application he/she is developing.

Comment: @Agop — Yes, that's what I was talking about.

Comment: Your explanation is elegant! I'd like to know that since 8000 rejects the response because it's not trusted, is there a way to overcome this merely on 8000 side?